# Is it possible to exec a command from an applet?

Tags: java, applet, exec

I want to do this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
  rt.exec("notepad");
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Inside an applet (called from a LOCAL html webpage) is it possible? I remember something about a security model in java but I am not sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can trusted 1.5 applets execute system commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240575/can-trusted-1-5-applets-execute-system-commands)

Comment: BTW - Why would you want to pull up (a blank) notepad from an applet?  If that is 'just an example', please supply of a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at this Q&A: [Can trusted 1.5 applets execute system commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240575/can-trusted-1-5-applets-execute-system-commands) for answer to your question.